# Differences between Animation and TranslateAnimation

Tags: android, android-animation, translate-animation

What's the difference between [Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html)  and [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)? Where should I use everyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation is the superclass of TranslateAnimation.
A TranslateAnimation changes the position of the animated view.
You can find all ainmation types in android here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html

Comment: When you say "changes the position of the animated view" you mean that the view will keep the new position after the animation? Is this the same than using `setFillAfter(true);`?

Comment: The actual position stays the same. If you would play the same animation several times it would start always at the same point. Use a AnimationListener to set the position after the animation has finished